# How do I update/define system metadata for an AWS S3 object while creating a presigned url using Node.js SDK

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sdk

I'm currently generating a pre-signed url to upload an object to my AWS s3 bucket
`const signedUrl = await s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', params);`

Here is my params object:

```
 const params = {
     Bucket: 'mybucket',
     Key: `mybucketpost-${Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10 ** 10)}.png`,
     ContentType: 'image/png',
     Metadata: {
     ContentType: 'image/png',
     },
     Expires: 36000
   }
```

I'm able to successfully generate a presigned URL and upload an object to my bucket, but when I'm trying to access the object using the `s3.getSignedUrl` method, the object gets downloaded instead of the png image opening up in my browser tab. Now with all the research I've done, I understand why that's happening. That's because the system-defined object metadata `Content-Type` for my object is still `binary/octet-stream`.
Even though I've attempted to change the Content-Type for the object I'm generating the presigned url for to `image/png`, it gets added as a user-generated metadata for the object `x-amz-meta-contenttype: image/png`.

So in my AWS console, the meta-data for my uploaded object are:

```
System defined  Cache-Control   no-cache
System defined  Content-Type    binary/octet-stream
User defined    x-amz-meta-contenttype  image/png
```

and unfortunately, this does not solve the issue of loading up the image in the browser tab.
I've tried changing the System defined meta-data `Content-Type` for an object directly through the AWS console to `image/png` and as expected, the object (png) opens up in my browser tab using the object URL, but I've not been able to find a way to change System Defined meta-data `Content-Type` using the AWS SDK for Node.js while generating the presigned URL using the `putObject` property. Need your help with the same. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem when I try to set the Content-Disposition metadata whiling uploading to S3. In my case, by deleteing the `Metadata` object inside params works for me.

The following is a [AWS JavaScript SDK example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html) that defines an `params` object. It suggests that in order to change an System Defined metadata, you don't need to specify it in Metadata object but rather define it directly inside `params` object. And anything you define inside Metadata object will become user defined.

```
var params = {
  Bucket: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
  Key: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
  ACL: private | public-read | public-read-write | authenticated-read | aws-exec-read | bucket-owner-read | bucket-owner-full-control,
  BucketKeyEnabled: true || false,
  CacheControl: 'STRING_VALUE',
  ContentDisposition: 'STRING_VALUE',
  ContentEncoding: 'STRING_VALUE',
  ContentLanguage: 'STRING_VALUE',
  ContentType: 'STRING_VALUE',
  ExpectedBucketOwner: 'STRING_VALUE',
  Expires: new Date || 'Wed Dec 31 1969 16:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)' || 123456789,
  GrantFullControl: 'STRING_VALUE',
  GrantRead: 'STRING_VALUE',
  GrantReadACP: 'STRING_VALUE',
  GrantWriteACP: 'STRING_VALUE',
  Metadata: {
    '<MetadataKey>': 'STRING_VALUE',
    /* '<MetadataKey>': ... */
  },
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For `getSignedURL(...)`  setting the `ResponseContentType` worked for me as below:

```
signedUrl = await s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', params);


 const params = {
     Bucket: 'mybucket',
     Key: `mybucketpost-${Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10 ** 10)}.png`,
     ResponseContentType: 'application/binary-stream',
     Expires: 36000
   }
```

In my case I want create 2 URLS,  one which will upon click download an mp4 file to disk(**ResponseContentType: 'application/binary-stream'**) and the second will pop open a browser tab and play the video(**ResponseContentType: 'video/mp4'**).

This works independent of what the system Content-Type value is in S3. Although if the value in S3 is set to video/mp4 you can actually leave out the ResponseContentType parameter and the default will be your S3 system content-type setting.